# OCmock expect/stub and doInvocation on class method

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocmock

I have a class method with a completion block being called in the method under test. So I want to stub this method and call

> [[[mock stub] loadImageForRelativeFilePath:[OCMArg any] completionBlock:[OCMArg any]] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation)

but I am getting compilation error that no instance method for selector.

Any alternative or any issue with way of access ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stub a class method in OCMock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810053/how-to-stub-a-class-method-in-ocmock)

Comment: Where is the method loadImageForRelativeFilePath:completionBlock: declared? Is the header file which declares the method definitely included by the test in which you try to stub it? Are you sure the name isn't misspelled?